# Quasar cannot find quasar extras namely material-icons, roboto font css and polyfills

Tags: vue.js, npm, yarnpkg, quasar

Each time I run quasar dev this message appears. 
The installation is pretty standard with pwa template.

These dependencies were not found:

- quasar-extras/material-icons/material-icons.css in ./.quasar/client-entry.js
- quasar-extras/roboto-font/roboto-font.css in ./.quasar/client-entry.js
- quasar-framework/dist/quasar.ie.polyfills.js in ./.quasar/client-entry.js

To install them, you can run: npm install --save quasar-extras/material-icons/material-icons.css quasar-extras/roboto-font/roboto-font.css quasar-framework/dist/quasar.ie.polyfills.js

Answer (score 1):

if you are using **quasar-cli**, firstly delete it due to **quasar-cli** doesn't include quasar-extras built-in. You can see this with running quasar info. after deleting **quasar-cli** please install

> npm i -g @quasar/cli

then run

> quasar dev

with this way error should be gone.

Comment: As well as the above I needed to run the command

Comment: npm add @quasar/extras

Comment: to get this working

Answer (score 0):

I think the quasar-cli should be tagged deprecated already. To solve this problem I simply remove the global installation, used the `vite` setup and currently I am running the quasar commands using `npx quasar`

Answer (score 0):

For me this helped :

```
npm install @quasar/extras
```